# Unable to upgrade from 16.04.1 to 16.04.3

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dpkg, update-manager

I was trying to upgrade from 16.04.1 to 16.04.3, currently the system is of version 16.04.1

```
menghan@menghan:~$ uname -ra
Linux menghan 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Then, I tried sudo apt-get update

In the end, I got

```
menghan@menghan:~$ sudo apt-get update
.........
.........
........
........
Reading package lists... Done
W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/bumblebee/stable/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

---

In this end, nothing is updated:

```
menghan@menghan:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
```

I'm aware that I got relatively tough laptop to get Ubuntu working properly on it, as it's got bbswitch, nividia driver, bumbble-bee (From memory, one of these things were broken when I was trying to install them, so I had to use an older version)....

My gut feeling is that one of these things cannot be properly updated, causing nothing to be updated in the end...

Comment: You actually have three separate, unrelated issues - each should be a separate question...except that each of those issues has already been Answered here many times. Read the first line, understand the problem the first line is describing, then use the Search box.

Comment: Hint: Why do you have 12.04 sources enabled on  16.04 system?

Comment: Hi user535733, what are the three separate issues you are referring to? If you think that they've been answered. Could you please put links for them?  Which line indicates that I have 12.04 sources enabled? I'm sorry, but this is confusing as hell.

Comment: @user535733, what do you mean the first line? I don't see any problems with the first line

Comment: The first line: `W: http://archive.canonical.com/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)`. Your problem here seems to be a Precise (12.04) repository enabled on a 16.04 system. Fix that.